# Is it OK to have a factory that produces factories?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, datatable, factory

## The Goal

I need to annotate `System.Data.DataTable`s on a per cell basis while tucking away the implementation details with the help of a generic interface.

### What I've tried

I discovered that `DataColumn`s have an `ExtendedProperties` collection on which you can add some specific logic - the thing is that the annotations don't really belong to a column nor to a row. Sure enough `DataRow`s don't have such a bag for data and I don't want to implement and test a whole `DataTable` derivative type just for some annotations

### The Current Solution

Since datatables don't have a notion of cells but instead you can only access individual values by `DataRow` and `DataColumn` I have been thinking about deriving from a data table and making it a factory of factories:

```
using System.Data;
class AnnotatedDataTable: DataTable, IFactory<DataRow, IFactory<DataColumn, IDataCellAnnotation>>
{
    // ...
    public IFactory<DataColumn, IDataCellAnnotation> Create(DataRow row)
    {
        return someAnnotationFactoryForTheGivenRow;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Another option would be to use a tuple as the key for the factory but I think this is just hiding the design problem I have for this kind of problem.

This really hurts my brain ... a factory doesn't seem to cut it in this situation. Any ideas whether having factories create factories is OK or not? Thanks!

Comment: http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/?joel.3.219431.12 welcome to factories' hell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dropped the factory of factories and finally went with another approach:

```cs
interface IDataCellAnnotation
{
    // Some annotations for a data cell ...
}

interface IAnnotatedTable
{
    IEnumerable<IDataCellAnnotation> GetCellAnnotations(System.Data.DataRow row);
}

class AnnotatedDataTable : DataTable, IAnnotatedTable
{
    // ...

    public IEnumerable<IDataCellAnnotation> GetCellAnnotations(System.Data.DataRow row)
    {
        return theAnnotationsForTheGivenRow;
    }
}
```

It doesn't hurt my brain anymore and it's much cleaner this way while still retaining the ability to handle the thingy as an `IAnnotatedTable` outside of my assembly.

Answer (score 0):

"Factory" is a term from the "desing patterns" category. It is merely a set of coding conventions that help to express (code) something.

What is ok or not ok from the perspective of maintainable/portable/etc. code should become clear once you **identify** the **actors** and **their tasks/roles and responsibilities**.

You can use e.g. UML sequence diagram (shows actors and their information exchange as time-sequence) or UML activity diagram with swimlanes (shows actors, data-only-objects and their flow) or another UML modeling tool.

Try drawing several **UML designs to decide what the system you are designing really looks like**.

Then apply some design patterns to encode it.

Factories are an implementation tool (how). Not the primary object observed in reality that is modeled in the digital space (what+why)

StackOverflow has the [uml](/questions/tagged/uml) tag that can help you to find some more tips.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an [abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

Interestingly enough, a very common pattern for their usage is to handle .... (drum roll) UIs!

The classic example is how to make sure that, if you're using a windowing theme (windows UI vs. Mac) that you don't accidentally/intentionally mix up widgets between themes; eg. Mac buttons with Windows style combo-boxes.

As an example, 
This is how [Java UIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/package-tree.html) do it.